# React setState causing strange error after removing child node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The setState function is causing a weird error in my `deleteVehicle` function

```
deleteVehicle(vid) {
    console.log(document.getElementById(vid).parentNode);
    document
        .getElementById(vid)
        .parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(vid));
        var current_no = this.state.no_of_vehicles;
        this.setState({ no_of_vehicles: current_no - 1 });
}
```

My `createVehicleElements` function is as follows:

```
createVehicleElements() {
    var vehicle_units = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.no_of_vehicles; i++) {
        var j = i + 1;
        vehicle_units.push(
            <div className="vehicle-unit" id={"v" + j} key={"v" + j}>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div className="vehicle-heading">
                    <p>Vehicle {j}</p>
                    <div
                        className="delete-vehicle"
                        onClick={() => this.deleteVehicle("v" + j)}
                    >
                        Delete
                    </div>
                </div>
                //... remaining code here
            </div>
        );
    }
    return vehicle_units;
}
```

Now when I click the delete button, it gives me this error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

However, if I remove the line `this.setState({ no_of_vehicles: current_no - 1 });` from my `deleteVehicle` function, my code gives the desired result i.e. it removes that particular vehicle element. I can't remove this line since this needs to be updated to keep my `createVehicleElements` function working properly.

I don't understand what's causing this error. How do I solve this?

Comment: When you edit the DOM that React expects to own, you will run into unexpected errors. What are you trying to achieve in `deleteVehicle`? You likely shouldn't be calling `removeChild` or other functions that manipulate the DOM.

Comment: the point of react is that you shouldn't have to directly interact with the DOM anymore to remove things or add things like that in the first place.